# User ID become primary key and autoincrement by it self

Tags: laravel, migration

I wanna make table with migration,
but when I execute there's an error massage

```
Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as key
```

[image]

but I'm not set user id as increment and primary key, why?

I'm a beginner anyway
here's my code

```
Schema::create('orders', function(Blueprint $table){

            $table->increments('order_id');
            $table->dateTime('order_date');
            $table->integer('order_status')->default(0);
            $table->integer('user_id', 10)->unsigned();
            $table->string('npk_user_approval', 10);
            $table->string('npk_ga_approval', 10);
            $table->dateTime('approval_user_at')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('approval_ga_at')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('reject_user_at')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('reject_ga_at')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('created_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('created_by', 50)->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('updated_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('updated_by', 50)->nullable();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
```

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @Gadzhev I'm using version 5.3

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of the Blueprint's `integer()` method is `$autoIncrement?`. You are passing a `10` which in fact it sets to auto increment. Here is the code taken from `Blueprint` class:

```
/**
 * Create a new integer (4-byte) column on the table.
 *
 * @param  string  $column
 * @param  bool  $autoIncrement
 * @param  bool  $unsigned
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\Fluent
 */
public function integer($column, $autoIncrement = false, $unsigned = false)
{
    return $this->addColumn('integer', $column, compact('autoIncrement', 'unsigned'));
}
```

So instead of passing the 10 (which you thought is the size), do this instead:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
```

is equivalent to creating integer column, unsigned, with autoIncrement is turned off.

To change the integer sizes, use the methods such as

- tinyInteger
- unsignedTinyInteger
- smallInteger
- unsignedSmallInteger
- ... and medium, big.